# How to create layered scroll-able pages in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to prepare a layout which looks like the image in [this link](https://github.com/shubhanshu02/InstiComplaints-App/raw/shubhanshu/assets/background.png). In this, the top page (white one) should contain other widgets while the bottom widget (the other colour) will contain the heading. The top page contains some TextFields. So when the keyboard shows up or the user swipes up, the border between the two pages should shift up ideally.

I tried making it using Stack widget with Container having curved corners in the following way, but it didn't work quite well.

```
Stack(children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200), color: Color(0xFF181D3D)),
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100)),
          color: Color(0xFF181D3D),
        ),
        height: 200,
        child: Heading(),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
        child: Contents(),
      ),
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve the shape in the picture, `BorderRadius` won't help because there are something other than just round corners. You need to draw a `Path` and use it to build a `CustomClipper` so you can clip the colored `Container` into a desired shape.

Just imagine you are drawing with precise coordinates when building the `Path` and you have different methods to draw. The size here means the size of the widget which has the `ClipPath` as child.

```
class CurveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size){
    Path path = Path()
      // set the "current point"
      ..addArc(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width/4, size.width/4), math.pi, -1.57)
      ..lineTo(9 * size.width / 10, size.width / 4)
      ..addArc(Rect.fromLTWH(3 * size.width / 4,  size.width / 4, size.width/4, size.width/4), math.pi + 1.57, 1.57)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.width/8);
      return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(oldCliper) => false;
}
```

I used the `ClipPath` to clip the blue part and put it in front of the white `Container` in the `Stack` widget. The `Stack` widget expands to cover its parent, the screen size `Container`, so the size in the `getClip()` function shown above refers to the screen size.

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(), color: Colors.white),
      ClipPath(
        clipper: CurveClipper(),
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          color: Colors.blue[900]
        )
      ),
    ],
  )
),
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the addArc in your getClip() function?

Comment: Sure. The `addArc()` function takes in a `Rect`, `startAngle` and `sweepAngle`. The function actually just draw circle inside the `Rect` you passed it but you can tell it where to start drawing and how much it draws with `startAngle` and `sweepAngle` in radian. The `Rect.fromLTWH()` lets you position the top left corner of the  `Rect` and define its size. @ShubhanshuSaxena

Comment: So, if I want to increase the blue region, i.e. to expand the blue part a little more downward, I would need to change the coordinates of the top-left corner of the first addArc(), then draw a horizontal line and then again draw an arc using addArc(). Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly how it works but you also need to enclose the shape, that's what all other `lineTo()` for.

Comment: You may want to read some more here. https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text fields in column and that column in single child scroll view